# Display an icon according to the file type

Tags: django

I want to show an icon for my attachment (according to file type).

```
def __str__(self):
    return format_html('<a href="%s"><img src="%s" width="300" height="300" /></a></br>' % (self.attach_file.url,icon/file/path,))
```

for this I have to keep file icons. is there any better way to acquire the icons in django?

Comment: What's wrong with this way? As suggestion: use css-classes?

Comment: since attached file type has no limits, I thought if there is a library or something would be easier than check the file type and get the right icon.

Comment: How many filetypes do you have? Maybe [django-awesome](https://github.com/redouane/django-fontawesome/blob/master/fontawesome/icons.yml) will suffice? Search for "File Type Icons" - there are 13 icons for filetypes.

Comment: In case you want to use your current collection of icons - I would look also into [django-filer](https://django-filer.readthedocs.io/en/0.9.6/extending_filer.html#create-some-other-model-that-uses-it). But it looks much more complicated. Although this could meet your needs. Maybe I compile my comments into an aswer a little later